# Searching in entire SharePoint site using REST API URI

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, rest, sharepoint-search

I am making a WPF application in which I require to retrieve the search results from the SharePoint site. The search should display results from the entire site including the subsites for that item. 
The URI which I have used thus far is :: **sites/amit/_api/search/query?querytext='amit'**

But querying using the mentioned URI is not giving me search results from the entire site (which are also far less than what is obtained when the search is performed in site itself). I want the search to include all the lists, discussions, people and all the subsites i.e. everything related to that item. So, please help me in knowing where I am going wrong and how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the mistake. The URL which I was using was correct. The only thing was that by default it was taking the row limit to 20. On increasing the row limit I was able to get complete results.